# variadic number of methods as template input parameter

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Is it possible to specify a member-function template parameter pack?
Something like this:

```
template <typename foo, void (foo::*bar)(void) ...>
void application()
{
}
```

None of my solutions work, and I would like to avoid putting every function that I'm gonna use in a struct.

Comment: What is the actual problem this is supposed to solve? Why do you need something like that(instead of just a plain and simple `typename F` (and an argument) to handle all kind of callable objects? Right now this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I have a large amount of methods that are supposed to be passed as input arguments, which makes it very inconvenient to wrap every single method inside structs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for this is

```
template <typename C, void (C::*...mfuncs)()>
void application()
{
    // ...
}
```

or with `typedef`:

```
template <typename C>
using MemberFunc = void (C::*)();

template <typename C, MemberFunc<C>...mfuncs>
void application();
```